# GroupBy All possible permutations

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Example dataset columns: ["A","B","C","D","num1","num2"]. So I have 6 columns - first 4 for grouping and last 2 are numeric and means will be calculated based on groupBy statements.
I want to groupBy all possible combinations of the 4 grouping columns.
I wish to avoid explicitly typing all possible groupBy's such as groupBy["A","B","C","D"] then groupBy["A","B","D","C"] etc.
I'm new to Python - in python how can I automate group by in a loop so that it does a groupBy calc for all possible combinations - in this case 4*3*2*1 = 24 combinations?
Ta.

Thanks for your help so far. Any idea why the 'a =' part isn't working?

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
group_by_vars = list(df.columns)[0:4]
perms = [perm for perm in itertools.permutations(group_by_vars)]
print list(itertools.combinations(group_by_vars,2))
a = [x for x in itertools.combinations(group_by_vars,group_by_n+1) for group_by_n in range(len(group_by_vars))]
```

a doesn't error I just get an empty object. Why???
Something like [comb for comb in itertools.combinations(group_by_vars,2)] is easy enough but how to get a = [x for x in itertools.combinations(group_by_vars,group_by_n+1) for group_by_n in range(len(group_by_vars))]??

Answer (score 0):

When you group by `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` and calculate the mean, you'll get one particular group `(a0, b0, c0, d0)` with a mean of `m0`.

When you permute the columns and group by `['A', 'B', 'D', 'C']`, you'll get one particular group `(a0, b0, d0, c0)` with a mean of `m0`.

In fact that those `m0` are the same.  All the groups are the same.  You will be duplicating the same exact calculations for every permutation... You just have 4! ways of ordering the tuples... why?

Comment: Yep. Truth be told I want all 2 and 3 variable permutations from these 4 then group by 4. I just didn't want to add all these specifics into the question based on the fact that it's more filler than anything. Truth be told I just want to know for when I have say 10 variables - I'd sooner automate the groupBy than manual type more than I must. Maybe I should have been clearer so I apologise for that. You make a great point. Highlights that we ignore order for these groupings which I am sure a future reader will appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import permutations

perms = [perm for perm in permutations(['A','B','C','D'])]
```

perms will then be a list of all the possible 24 permutations

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. Any idea why this isn't working? import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))

group_by_vars = list(df.columns)[0:4]
perms = [perm for perm in permutations(group_by_vars)]

print list(itertools.combinations(group_by_vars,2))

a = [itertools.combinations(group_by_vars,group_by_n+1) for group_by_n in range(len(group_by_vars))]

Comment: You should probably either update the question with this info so that the code is formatted properly, or post a new question. Either way, make sure to include the specific error and be precise as possible with the question.

Comment: Answer updated. I pressed upvote on your answer but my rating's not high enough to actually do anything. It appears that Python tutorials have fairly simple list comprehension examples and then I've hit a snag first go at one I actually need in real life.

Comment: Figured it out.... [list(itertools.combinations(group_by_vars,i)) for i in xrange(1,len(group_by_vars)+1)] ... Why? No idea, Python's special I guess. Apparently removing the 'x for x in ' bit makes a difference given the solution I'm after.